# Facebook Sharer doesn't read meta tags on my whole domain

Tags: facebook, dns, share

I have properly configured Open Graph meta tags on my webpage so when someone shared a page on my web everything worked perfectly - Title, Description, Thumbnail.... Until a month ago. Now when I try to share a page, firstly everything appears correctly - title, description, thumbnail, but when I post it, it's reduced to the domain name. Instead of title and description the sharer puts www.mydomain.com and the thumbnail is removed completely. See the screenshot to see what I mean - August 22, everything ok, then it went wrong.

http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/2635/wwwsvobodainfo.png

I tried to hack the meta tags, but Facebook Debugger showed no errors and eventually I figured out that the meta tags don't play any role in this problem. I created simple 5-line html document, just head/title/body, uploaded it, shared it and the result was the same. But then I uploaded this simple document to different domain and suddenly the Facebook Sharer recognized the title and displayed it properly. So it seems to me that it's related to the whole domain, in other words, Facebook "blocks" my whole web!

And the situation is a little bit more messy. The real owner of this web created long time ago a simple Facebook Page to promote this web. As far as I know, this page is not "connected" to the real web, only the name is the same. Then we wanted to monitor users (liking, sharing...) so we registered the domain into Facebook Insights. And now, when I was trying to get this working, I registered a new Facebook Application with my different Facebook account (my was verified, owner's wasn't) in order to get an app_id which I could put to the meta tags. Well it didn't work, but I'm now worried that something inside Facebook went wrong and that's why the whole web is ignored.

Last thing - I found some thread about exactly the same problem but it was started almost 2 year ago (http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=46573&p=2) and some official Facebook guy claimed that it was just a bug which was going to be fixed soon. Well obviously it's here again and lasts almost a month now.

EDIT: Simple Like button seems to be working well, but when I like a page and try to comment it, the problem occurs as described above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All **dot info** domains (that i had checked) have this problem.

It's a Facebook bug!! I have the same problem on my domain, so I hope FB will resolve it soon :/

Answer (score 1):

There is existing bug report on Facebook for the same problem. Could anybody that is experiencing the same issue please report it to Facebook http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/171541966257908

Comment: Done - I hope they will fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, same thing here and started about a month ago, mid-August.  I spent two full days beating my head against the monitor. The FB page is here http://www.facebook.com/kelownaevents - scroll down to Sept 8th post to see what's happenning. Links to all other websites are displayed properly, but not our own.

Moreover, these posts with links do not show up in Newsfeeds.

As described, modifying meta properties and setting up a separate Facebook app did not do a thing.

The sample URL is http://www.kelownaevents.info/index.php?option=events&main_id=15402

When using Facebook to create a link, the thumbnail and the image are displaying properly, **but as soon as "Share" button is clicked**, the title is replaced by a generic URL, image and description disappear.

I found a thread on Etsy.com that showed that Etsy had a similar problem in March 2011.
- etsy.com/teams/7718/site-help/discuss/6805652/page/1

Comment: If feels good not to be alone :) So I assume this is really a Facebook problem and I tried to ask them directly using this form https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=questions_bug ...I hope it'll help.

Comment: I have already done that also.. I think it may be a piece of code on our pages that does something.. Why would it affect only two websites? Ok, may be a handful...

Comment: Well I don't think that's a piece of code causing this - as I wrote in the original question, I made a simple HTML page and uploaded it to the affected website - it didn't work as expected. But then I uploaded the same file to another website and it worked like a charm. So I think it's related to the whole domain - that means that something is wrong inside Facebook. The question is whether we can do something about it - like there is a undiscovered configuration form or something like that :) Yesterday, I sent this question directly to Facebook but I haven't heart from them yet...

Comment: are you also having problems AFTER "Share" button is clicked and not before?

Comment: Exactly. In the first moment it looks good, title and thumbnail are properly displayed but then when I hit the share button everything goes wrong... as you're describing :) the page is http://www.svoboda.info - you can try it.

Comment: I just figured it out too, before I even saw the answer below - it must have something to do with "info" domains!